# Unit Test with Jest , Class constructor

Tags: class, jestjs

How to test the following  Class that has validation in construction using set.

```
const BaseParameter = class BaseParameter {
  constructor(addr, fullname, value) {
    this.addr = addr;
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.value = value;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(value) {
    if (typeof value !== "number") {
      throw new TypeError(`Parameter ${this.fullname} should be a number`);
    }
    this._value = value;
  }
};
```

I have tried this following method of Jest.

```
test("BaseParameter with invalid constructor", () => {
  expect(new BaseParameter("test", "test fullname", "a")).toThrowError(
    TypeError
  );
});
```

but throws the error and the pass fails.

Answer (score 1):

The docs have clear example, I just has stuck

```
test("BaseParameter with invalid constructor", () => {
  expect(() => new BaseParameter("test", "test fullname", "a")).toThrowError(
    TypeError
  );
});
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks